# Extend list at time of creation in python, how?

Tags: python, list

Here is the sample dict one

```
one = {'a': 1,'b': 3}
```

and the second dict is

```
second = {'x': 45,'y': 45}
```

here is the key container(of type `list`)

```
key_con = one.keys()
key_con = key_con.extend(second.keys())
```

and all work good.
But i try to shorten the code
like this

```
key_con = one.keys().extend(second.keys())
```

now, `key_con` is `NoneType` 
i want to make this key container in one line code.
how to achieve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
key_con = one.keys() + second.keys()
```

`extend` modifies the list in-place and doesn't return anything. Are you sure your first snippet works?

Comment: @lokeshjain2008 https://gist.github.com/4564328 is just copying and pasting the code you gave above.

Comment: @ThomasK How did this happen? This means that i am not alone with these questions.

Comment: Still why `key_con = one.keys().extend(second.keys())` didn't work and first one worked.

Comment: @lokeshjain2008 - I mean, I just copied your first example, to show that it doesn't work either.

Comment: @lokeshjain2008 `extend` doesn't return a value, it updates the list in place. Neither of your examples will work.

Answer (score 1):

While [the other answer by Pavel Anossov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14399044/722121) answered the question you explicitly asked, I would still argue that it's not the best solution to the problem at hand. Dictionaries are unordered, and can't have duplicate keys, so using a list to store the keys is inherently misleading and a bad idea.

Instead, it is a much better idea to store this data in a set - sets don't have order, and can't contain duplicates, and so fill this role much more effectively.

In Python 3.x, [`dict.keys()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.keys) gives [a set-like dictionary view](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views), so this would be best done with:

```
key_con = one.keys() | two.keys()
```

We use the `|` (binary or) operator, which, on sets and set-like objects, signals a [union](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/stdtypes.html#set.union) (all elements in one set *or* the other).

In 2.7, the same behaviour can be obtained with [`dict.viewkeys()`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#dict.viewkeys):

```
key_con = one.viewkeys() | two.viewkeys()
```

In older versions, then we can use [`dict.iterkeys()`](http://docs.python.org/2.6/library/stdtypes.html#dict.iterkeys) with [`set()`](http://docs.python.org/2.6/library/stdtypes.html#set):

```
key_con = set(one.iterkeys()) | set(two.iterkeys())
```